# For loop is not working correctly in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am saving some input data into database. Using for loop I am trying to save the input data in different rows.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $day ; $i++) { 
    $activity->event_id = $request->event_id;
    $activity->created_by = $id;
    $activity->index = $request->index[$i];
    $activity->activity_title = $request->activity_title[$i];
    $activity->activity_details = $request->activity_details[$i];

    $activity->save();
}
```

The problem is, it only saves the last value. Suppose if day = 2 it saves the information of the second index of my arrays. Ignores the first index value. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems you are reusing the same object $activity, so it just update the line written in the first iteration with the data of the second

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instantiate your `$activity` within the loop, e.g.

```
for ($i=0; $i < $day ; $i++) { 
    $activity = new Activity();

    $activity->event_id = $request->event_id;
    $activity->created_by = $id;
    $activity->index = $request->index[$i];
    $activity->activity_title = $request->activity_title[$i];
    $activity->activity_details = $request->activity_details[$i];

    $activity->save();
}
```

Right now, you're just overwriting the same instance every iteration, which explains why only the last value remains.

Comment: Yep that's the solution. Thanks @EmilePels